# How to determine the purchase price if the profit percentage is known

Tags: python, python-fractions

I want to do a story problem on the following math.

A merchant sells an item at a price $210.00 and profit 5% of the price buy. Determine the purchase price the item.

The answer is like the following [image: picture].

Then, I solved it with the code below.

```
  from fractions import Fraction
  def purchase_price(pp, profit):
     x = pp + profit
     return x
  pp = 100
  profit = 5
  a = pp + profit
  a = 210 * Fraction(100, 105)
  print('${:,.2f}'.format(a))
```

the result is like this.

```
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Fraction.__format__
```

And I, who is still a beginner, want to ask... does my code look neat and clean?

My study materials are [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-cost-price-from-given-selling-price-and-profit-or-loss-percentage/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926840/how-to-check-change-between-two-values-in-percent).

Thank you, any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
profit = 0.05
sell = 210
print(f"Purchase price: ${(sell/(1+profit)):.2f}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use python's normal fraction `100/105`

Your code should look like this

```
def purchase_price(pp, profit):
     x = pp + profit
     return x
pp = 100
profit = 5
a = pp + profit
a = 210 * (100/105)
print('${:,.2f}'.format(a))
```